# javascript on click function is not working at all

Tags: javascript, html

Second function, which should take me to `player2.html`, isn't working for some reason. Is there any mistake in syntax or format?

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function()
{
    location.href="player.html";
}

//**>>>**This doesn't work. Button does nothing when clicked****
document.getElementById("next").onclick = function()
{
   location.href="player2.html";

}

document.getElementById("startgame").onclick = function()
{
    location.href = "gameboard.html";
}
```

**This is index.html**

```
<div class="container">

    <header>
        <h1>
            Tic Tac Toe
        </h1>
    </header>


    <div class="frame">
        <div>
            <button id="start">Start</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>Exit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<script src="main.js"></script>
```

**This is player.html**

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="frame">
            <label for="player">Enter player1 name : </label>
            <input type="textbox" id="player">
            <div>            
                <button id="next">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: We also need to see your HTML that contains the `next` button.

Comment: From what i see it should work. you probably need to Check the console and see if there's any errors in there, and posting your html too would help :)

Comment: No.
It works fine,only if i put the function in different .js file  but when put together doesnt work. Is there any logic behind that.

Comment: @saujan Yeah you probably have an error in your JS somewhere. If there are syntax errors, nothing in your script will run. If there are runtime errors, your script will stop there. Look at your debug console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: You player.html page does not have an element with id start, so your script will fail on the first line where it tries to set onclick on an undefined object.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli yeah that was the reason. So how do i fix this problem. I want all of the function in same .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is causing an error when you load the `player.html` page because there's no element with an id of "start" on that page.

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function()
{
    location.href="player.html";
}
```

You'll get an error at the top of the JS file, which breaks the other buttons.  I recommend jQuery, as it won't error when an ID isn't found when binding an onclick event.  In jQuery do this.

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    location.href="player.html";
});
```

**If you don't want to use jQuery, here's the JavaScript way**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("start");

if(elem){
    elem.onclick = function()
    {
        location.href="player.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: i followed your javascript way.
Can u plz tell me 
how if statement worked??

Comment: Yes.  IF returns a boolean, yes or no.  If something is NULL, the IF fails.  In this case, if the element is null, the IF statement fails.